TupleElementNamesAttribute is missing from ValueTuple CustomAttributes
Is there a setting somewhere that disables this feature?  I am coding a .NET 7 assembly, and if I run code like this:
(string Name, int Age) tuple1 = ("Name1", 25);
tuple1.GetType().GetCustomAttributes().Dump();

It does not have the attribute present.


That's a local variable - there's generally no need for those to have attributes applied to them, because nothing other than the compiler (which has the source) needs to know about them.
Try writing a method with that tuple type as a return type, and I think you'll see the attributes... but on the return aspect of the method, not on any type. (The type itself will just be the tuple type with suitable type arguments. There aren't different Type objects for tuple types with different element names.)
You can get at the return attributes using MethodInfo.ReturnTypeCustomAttributes.GetCustomAttributes:
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Foo");
        foreach (var attr in method
            .ReturnTypeCustomAttributes
            .GetCustomAttributes(false))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(attr);
        }
    }
    
    public static (int x, int y) Foo() => default;
}

Output:
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TupleElementNamesAttribute


@Terry: There's no such thing as "the type of the method" - I've reworded my answer to avoid implying that there is. I'd expected calling GetCustomAttributes on the MethodInfo itself to return the attribute. I'm trying ReturnTypeCustomAttributes now.
